# Unable to create Videoconferences sessions with Tokbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tokbox, rexml

The app create sessions for videoconferences and one of the values is a session id that takes from from tokbox. This was working for a lot of time, so in this days started to get the following error many attempts, and many other attempts runs ok, here the message from console:

```
REXML::ParseException (Missing end tag for 'hr' (got "body")
Line: 6
Position: 169
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
):
```

All seems that missing content from the tokbox id, no code change while this time lapse since this start happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Update the gem, Tokbox started to remove support from no secure connections.

Also you need to change OpenTokSDK class names to OpenTok.