# Got an OpenTokException. The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>"

Tags: java, opentok

Our application was working fine suddenly a strange exception throws from the **opentok** while trying to create the session.

Could you please suggest us to, what has to be done to avoid this exception?

Exception details are given below:

```
Caused by: com.opentok.exception.OpenTokException:
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 3; The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>". at 
    com.opentok.util.TokBoxXML.<init>(TokBoxXML.java:27) at 
    com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK.do_request(OpenTokSDK.java:201) at 
    com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK.create_session(OpenTokSDK.java:182) at 
    com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK.create_session(OpenTokSDK.java:150) at 
    com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK$create_session.call(Unknown Source) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42) at 
    com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK$create_session.call(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the API unexpectedly encountered an HTML error page. Have you checked your internet/proxy settings?

Comment: Does it happen 100% of the times?  What version of the OpenTok Java SDK are you using? 
Can you do a quick test with a python script (or other language) to confirm your credentials are correct?  https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Python-SDK

Comment: This could be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134423/unable-to-create-videoconferences-sessions-with-tokbox  Make sure you upgrade your SDK.

Comment: I have checked by upgrading the OpenToke SDK to 2.3.0 but still get same issue.